# Postgres: How can I restrict my query to return one enterprise?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query keeps returning both enterprises that have the prefix name, and I want to restrict it to just one.

```
    SELECT e.company,
       to_char(a.timestamp, 'yyyy/mm')AS "Year, Month",
       count(1)AS "Total Actions"
FROM activities a
JOIN users u ON a.trackid=u.trackid
JOIN enterprises e ON u.company=e.company
WHERE TIMESTAMP > (CURRENT_DATE - interval '12 months')
  AND user_state = 'active'
  AND user_type != 'BAR'
  AND enterprise LIKE 'Foo Enterprise'
  And enterprise != 'Foo Cyber'
  AND LEFT(actionname, 4) NOT IN
    (SELECT actionname
     FROM Actions
     WHERE action_group='NoUserAction')
GROUP BY e.company,
         to_char(a.timestamp, 'yyyy/mm')
ORDER BY to_char(a.timestamp, 'yyyy/mm') DESC, e.company
```

My results are showing both 'Foo Enterprise' and 'Foo Cyber' where I don't want to see 'Foo Cyber'.

A sample of the data this query returns even using NOT LIKE '%cyber%'is as follows:

Foo Cyber   2018/09 192

Foo Enterprise  2018/09 191

Foo Cyber   2018/08 406

Foo Enterprise  2018/08 1457

Foo Cyber   2018/07 2144

Foo Enterprise  2018/07 1106

Comment: Try this `  And enterprise not like 'Foo Cyber'`  . Can you show us a table with the results ?

Comment: can you change or add... `e.company not like ... ` . You are display `e.company` but your are trying to filter with enterprise. This doesn't match.

Comment: `WHERE TIMESTAMP > ...` Please qualify your references. (And:your question is unreadable. And: `timestamp` is a reserved word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try changing your query condition to the following examples:

```
  And enterprise not like 'Foo Cyber'
```

OR

And lower(enterprise) not like '%cyber%'

The query you have should work so there could be something going on with spaces or with upper/lower case.

### Update

The problem is that you are displaying `e.company` but you are trying to filter with enterrise.

Please change your variable to `e.company`. So Example:

` And e.company not like 'Foo Cyber'

Comment: Updating both enterprise variables to e.company resolved this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This logic:

```
WHERE  . . .
      AND enterprise LIKE 'Foo Enterprise'
      AND enterprise != 'Foo Cyber'
       . . .
```

can only return `'Foo Enterprise'` (all the boolean expressions are connected using `AND`).  The first condition is rather restrictive -- more so than the `!=`.

I think your actual query is a bit different.

Comment: I am getting identical results:
`WHERE . . . 
  AND enterprise like 'Foo Enterprise'
  AND enterprise != 'Foo Cyber'`

Foo Cyber 2018/09 192
Foo Enterprise 2018/09 191
Foo Cyber 2018/08 406
Foo Enterprise 2018/08 1457

Comment: @ForrestBear . . . This logic *cannot* return `'Foo Cyber'`, because it does not match `'Foo Enterprise'`.  Period.  You connectors are all `AND`s and this does not match.